# Javascript not working in IPhone

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, safari

I have write code to change color at run time using Javascript. It work well on Desktop and Andriod Mobile Phones but It is not working on IPhone 5 and 6, I have also tested with Safari in Desktop it works fine on Desktop Safari but not works in Iphone Safari.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Color invertor is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get Scripterrors when clicking the buttons:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function         (index):181

```
document.getElementById("logoimg")
```

does not return an element as there is none with this id.

If you fix this it may will work :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work on my iPhone 6, the page didn't crash or throw an error. have you made sure that JavaScript is turned on in the Safari settings of your phone? It's Settings > Safari > Advanced and theres a toggle switch for turing JavaScript on or off.

Answer (score 1):

you probably have to toggle javascript on your iphone in settings... have you tried with a third party browser like chrome on your iPhone? did it work?